# Open link WebBrowser or console in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a problem from the WebBrowser and the terminal in c #, I can not deal with opening the link,

```
string link = "https://ssl.filmweb.pl/api?version=1.0&appId=android&methods=getFilmInfoFull%20[107404]\n&signature=1.0,abbe0aaf4fcc5c56327c977ee07d72b6";

this.webb.Navigate(link, null, null, "User-Agent: ..."); or the same link,
```

response from windows and android browser

```
ok ["Piraci z Karaibów: Skrzynia umarlaka","Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest",7.83812,222891,"Fantasy,Przygodowy",2006,150,119,"http://www.filmweb.pl/Skrzynia.Umarlaka/discussion",1,1,"/74/04/107404/7518098.2.jpg",null,"2006-06-24","2006-07-21",0,0,0,"USA","Jack Sparrow musi spłacić dług zaciągnięty wobec kapitana Latającego Holendra. Uniknie śmierci, gdy znajdzie i zniszczy serce Davy'ego Jonesa ukryte w Skrzyni Umarlaka."] t:43200
```

response from WPF or console

```
err 10, Signature value is incorrect
```

Please help solve the problem

My code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Filmweb
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var webb = new WebBrowser();
            var link = "https://ssl.filmweb.pl/api?version=1.0&appId=android&methods=getFilmInfoFull%20[107404]\n&signature=1.0,abbe0aaf4fcc5c56327c977ee07d72b6";
            this.webb.Navigate(link);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Filmweb.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="webb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517"/>

</Grid>
```

firewall is disabled, the code seems to be correct, still not working, can cause lies somewhere else?

Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: i successfully navigate to a frame.

Comment: please your code, maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Why? I dont know, yesterday there were 2 votes down

Comment: I voted you up to equal ... glad you found an answer i was offline due to work. Some dudes on this site just patrol and down vote without giving a reason. I think they may have small man hoods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is related with `\n` in your url string.

**Works**

```
var url = @"https://ssl.filmweb.pl/api?version=1.0&appId=android&methods=getFilmInfoFull%20[107404]\n&signature=1.0,abbe0aaf4fcc5c56327c977ee07d72b6";
var res = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

**Doesn't work (err 10, Signature value is incorrect)**

```
var url = "https://ssl.filmweb.pl/api?version=1.0&appId=android&methods=getFilmInfoFull%20[107404]\n&signature=1.0,abbe0aaf4fcc5c56327c977ee07d72b6";
var res = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

All you need is a **`@`** :)

See this:  **[String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

So all you need is just escape your `\n` symbol with additional slash: `https://ssl.filmweb.pl/api?version=1.0&appId=android&methods=getFilmInfoFull [107404]\\n&signature=1.0,abbe0aaf4fcc5c56327c977ee07d72b6`

Comment: This code works, but not for me, maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: `var responseMessage = new HttpClient().GetAsync("https://ssl.filmweb.pl/api?version=1.0&appId=android&methods=getFilmInfoFull%20[107404]\n&signature=1.0,abbe0aaf4fcc5c56327c977ee07d72b6").Result;` Try to inspect what will you get in your response message? Is is http status code is Ok. Do you have fiddler?

Comment: I do not have a library httpclient in system.net it does not exist

Comment: It was just for testing, you can always add this. I get your problem and compare two requests from httpclient code and from browser. It seems like httpclient encode `\n` symbol:

Comment: I don't like the [history of your editions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19746959/revisions). I think you copied your final answer from @L.B.

Comment: My final answer i cut from my previous version, because answer was to complicated. Furthermore I was delete post when i see that somebody give a clear answer, but than i decide to restore it for history